# What does this code do in perl

Tags: perl

The input to perl is like this:

```
ID NALT NMIN NHET NVAR SING TITV QUAL DP G|DP NRG|DP
PT-1RTW 1 1 1 4573 1 NA 919.41 376548 23.469 58
PT-1RTX 0 0 0 4566 0 NA NA NA 34.5866 NA
PT-1RTY 1 1 1 4592 1 NA 195.49 189549 24.0416 18
PT-1RTZ 0 0 0 4616 0 NA NA NA 44.1474 NA
PT-1RU1 0 0 0 4609 0 NA NA NA 28.2893 NA
PT-1RU2 2 2 2 4568 2 0 575.41 330262 28.2108 49
PT-1RU3 0 0 0 4617 0 NA NA NA 35.9204 NA
PT-1RU4 0 0 0 4615 0 NA NA NA 30.5878 NA
PT-1RU5 0 0 0 4591 0 NA NA NA 26.2729 NA
```

This is the code:

```
perl -pe 'if($.==1){@L=split;foreach(@L){$_="SING.$_";}$_="@L\n"}'
```

I sort of guessed it is processing the first line to add SING to each word. but what does the last part `$_="@L\n"` do? without this, this code doesn't work.

Comment: The last part reassigns the edited first line (`SING.text`) to the default variable `$_`, which is then printed with a `"\n"` along with the other lines.

Comment: It alters first line in the file; https://eval.in/844205

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-p` command line switch makes perl process input (or files listed at command line)   "line by line" and print processed lines. The line content is stored in `$_` variable. `$_="@L\n"` assign new value to `$_` before it is printed.

Shorter version: `perl -pe 'if($.==1){s/(^| )/$1SING./g}'`

---

Deparsed (more readable) one-liner above:

`perl -MO=Deparse -pe 'if($.==1){@L=split;foreach(@L){$_="SING.$_";}$_="@L\n"}'`

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = readline ARGV)) {
    if ($. == 1) {
        @L = split(' ', $_, 0);
        foreach $_ (@L) {
            $_ = "SING.$_";
        }
        $_ = "@L\n";
    }
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last line combines the modified words into a full line and assigns it to `$_`, which is what will be printed after processing each line when `-p` is used.  (You might have inferred this from [the `perlrun` manual section on `-p`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#*-p*).)